# VB.Net - How best to write a LOT of data to csv

Tags: vb.net, csv, stringbuilder

I am querying years of data and exporting it to CSV like this:

```
Data Description, Timestamp, Value
Temperature, 8/28/2019 08:00:00, 75.5
```

Initially I was writing each point to CSV which takes a very long time, but does not incur memory issues.

Now I am storing in a stringbuilder and then writing to CSV.  However, this will run out of memory if the dataset is too large.

Is there some other trick I can use?  Or do I have to purge the Stringbuilder to file every once in a while to keep from hogging memory?  I'm assuming there is a better way that I do not know of.

Thanks!

Comment: While rather opinion based, you can open a stream to the file and write the data directly to the file as it is processed

Comment: What does *querying years of data* mean specifically? There may be a way to export it directly from your database server without having to do it yourself, but you've not provided any details.

Comment: It isn't a database server, it is a historian (binary).  I am querying it into a datatable, but it looks like the data in the post above.  So - I felt it was enough information for someone, sorry about that.

Comment: "years" isn't really a quantifiable amount. How much data are we talking, in MB (or GB or whatever)? At what size are you running out of memory with StringBuilder? How much memory does the computer have which is running this code? "A very long time" is equally vague. How long does it take when you write it a point at a time? How long would be acceptable? P.S. By a "point" do you mean a single data item? Or a single line? It's a bit unclear. P.P.S. Some code for each approach would help us to be clear exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I don't have any truly useful experience in this area, but I'd think that the best solution would be to open a file stream, and write as you go.  I'd give this a try.  It is possible that it's more efficient to write in larger chunks than many small ones (?), in which case you could queue up rows in batches, and flush to the file when you reach predetermined points.  Alternatively, any experience with SSIS?  This is the sort of thing that SSIS was designed for.

Comment: One option might be to have the writing being done on a secondary thread.  You could use a `ConcurrentQueue` and simply add each record to that in the main thread and then have the secondary thread writing from the queue to a file as long as there is data to write.  When it finds the queue empty, it could sleep for a short time and then check again.

Comment: Could be seen a s bit of overkill for this particular problem.  There are plenty of tools available via nugets/VS Market that write out data in various formats.  Have you considered off loading the file handling to an specialised tool?